# Site URL in editor in Joomla 2.5

Tags: email, joomla, joomla2.5

Is it possible to get site URL on HTML Editor in **joomla 2.5**. I need to give an image URL for email body.

Code

```
<img src="<?php JURI::base()?>/templates/dayo/images/sign.png" width="200" />
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: post you code what you have tried up to now

Comment: `<img src="<?php echo JURI::base()?>/templates/temp1/images/header.png" width="200" />'    i wrote this in html editor from backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the string replace function in email body.

Inside the editor you have to place a code `[image]` .On Getting the Post values you have to replace the string `[image]` to the image url.

Example code for string replace:

```
$mailbody = "mail body value [image] and description";
$imageurl = '';
$body     = str_replace("[image]", $imageurl, $mailbody);
```